# How to add custom action to Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to be able to press Ctrl+Shift+A and then type my command name (e.g. `checkstyle`) to execute a command from command line (e.g. `./gradlew checkStyle`). How can I do this?

Searching for this reveals only non-relevant suggestions, such as [custom action for plugin development](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/action_system/working_with_custom_actions.html#creating-a-custom-action) or [intention actions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intention-actions.html#)

Comment: Maybe this plugin can help https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9448-run-configuration-as-action.
Or, you can press `Alt+Shift+F10` to opel all run configurations window where you can type name of your run configureation (`checkstyle`)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this plugin

Answer (score 2):

To add new actions, go to Settings -> Tools -> External Tools. Check some examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then you can trigger them with Actions (Ctrl+Shift+A) or Search Everywhere (Shift+Shift). You can also add these tools to the toolbar by right clicking on existing action button:

[image]

And then:

[image]

So you will get:

[image] [image] [image]