# Android Studio BumbleBee pair wifi not working

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-11, android-studio-bumblebee

I am trying to connect my Android 11 device with the android studio over adb wifi but it is not working.

I updated to the latest stable bumblebee and updated my SDK
I tried turning off the firewall on my pc but it is the same result.

When I use the QR code method my android phone just shows "pairing device" and nothing happens
If I try the code method, the android studio just shows "searching for devices" but nothing happens

and, yes, I enabled wireless debugging on my phone and I am connected to the same wifi network.

I don't know if the problem is with my computer or phone. I do not have any other Android11+ phone to try with

Comment: Please update your android build tools to version 32.1.0-rc1

Comment: updated the build tools, tried both methods. same result. not working

Comment: I've fixed this issue by allowing firewall connection for adb.exe

Comment: I uhh just closed and re-opened Android Studio.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I was having the same problem as you. Neither pairing by QR nor by pairing code worked.

So I tried connecting by typing `adb connect [phone_ip]:[port]` in the terminal and that worked flawlessly. Didn't even need to plug the phone into the computer with a USB. Your phone will tell you the IP and port right above the "pair with QR code" option inside the Wi-Fi debugging setting. Just connect to that address.

Comment: but then i would need to use the adb connect command everytime i need to connect the device right?

Comment: nevermind, i created a batch file that automates the adb connection

Comment: Connect works on my android 12 device only after pairing phone and pc from time to time. Port on my device changes after each session. :-(

Comment: @FaysalAhmet Can you share it please

Comment: Thank you @VIBrunazo +1 for saving my day

Comment: On new android versions you need to use adb pair {ip}:{port}, press enter and it will prompt you a message to provide the pair code. Both the port which changes everytime and the pair code can be found in the developer options-> wireless debugging

Answer (score 137):

I had this issue; it paired fine the first time in-app but never worked again when trying to pair or connect directly from Android Studio.

What I now do to connect/pair is the following:

- Open your phone's settings and be sure to enable wireless debugging in developer options
- Click `Pair device with pairing code`, and keep it on that screen.
- Now, go into a terminal and `cd` into the `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\sdk\platform-tools` directory.
- After that, type `adb pair <PHONE_IP>:<PHONE_PORT>`
- Input the pairing code when prompted
- Finally, run `adb connect <PHONE_IP>:<PHONE_PORT_PROVIDED_ABOVE_PAIR_WITH_QR_BUTTON>`, and it should connect; Android Studio will automatically detect the connection, so that's it!

Comment: i just use adb connect without all the previous steps and it works just fine. no need for code or using android studio. i just enable wireless debugging and enter ip port displayed in wireless debugging screen

Comment: gotcha haha, glad it worked out

Comment: `adb connect [ip]:[port]` did the trick for me.

Comment: "Failed: Unable to start pairing client"  after input the pairing code. Is there any solution?

Comment: Started to work after manual ping to device https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64670288/android-11-wifi-adb-error-unable-to-start-pairing-client/67948492#67948492

Comment: thanks so much, this is a great help, as I'm otherwise unable to keep this working reliably.

Comment: Verify if the ip address of the device is typed correctly or not. In my case, i mistyped the ip address which caused the error.

Comment: Perfect, i prefered this instead of allowing untrested connections. Thank you!

Comment: This works great but now logcat doesn't show any logs for my app

Comment: Leave open these screens...
In AS, open `Pair Devices Using Wi-Fi -> Pair using pairing code`
On phone `Pair device with pairing code`
In terminal 
1. `abd pair <PHONE IP*>:<PORT*>` i.e. `adb pair 111.111.1.1:12345`
2. when prompted `Enter pairing code: <PAIRING CODE*>` i.e. `Enter pairing code: 999999`
*from phone's `Pair with device` modal

Comment: adb pair 192.168.0.124:44111
Enter pairing code: 484165
error: protocol fault (couldn't read status message): Undefined error: 0.  Any help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Great answer. I had to have AS 'Pair devices over Wi-Fi' window open on 'Pair using pairing code' for it to work.

Answer (score 34):

Go to `Settings -> Build, Execution... -> Debugger -> Built-in Server`

and in the `Built-in Server` option set the value of `Port` as the same port you see in your phone and tick the **Can accept external connections**

after that go to wireless pairing and your device will show now

Comment: but now if the port is changed i would need to reconfigure it in the options, using adb connect seems a bit more convenient.

Comment: In my case I have to check "Allow unsigned requests" to make it work

Comment: It's there in paired device but not showing in android studio active device list

Answer (score 19):

I tried everything to fix this and nothing worked. In frustration, I went for a walk. When I came back - it worked.

So while I can't say for sure what fixed it, **try turning your phone's WiFi off then on again.**

Answer (score 15):

Enable wifi debug on your phone.

Then write in terminal of android studio:
Navigate to platform-tools

```
cd %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

and then:

```
./adb pair [192.xxx.xxx.xxx]:[xxxxx] the data you get from pair with code tab
```

Press enter.

Then type your pair password.

Then

```
./adb connect [192.xxx.xxx.xxx]:[xxxxx] your data from pair via wifi
```

If not working again just restart phone and try again

Comment: The moment the device showed up for me in Android Studio was after the `adb pair` command. I also added the `adb` to the parth variables to make sure Android Studio could execute it. Then fill in the code in Android Studio. Then it said `Connecting to device` and that the paring could take up to 2 minutes. I wonder if that dialog will ever end... And, it didn't connect saying there was an issue :(

Answer (score 4):

It may be worth your while to ensure:

1. The relevant API is installed in Android Studio (either 30 or 31/"S" since this is a feature only available on phones running Android 11 and up).
2. adb.exe is not blocked by your system's firewall (on Windows, check this in Windows Security > Firewall and network protection > allow an app through firewall).
3. The latest build-tools are installed, as mentioned in the comments.

After that, the connection wizard at least recognized my device (Samsung Note 10), but failed to connect and gave a generic error message. I avoided this by using `adb pair <ip-address>:<port> <code>` as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71347583/13351293) answer. Seems like this feature still has a ways to go.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have a galaxy s10e, and **I need to put my phone in charge and activate wifi debugging and when it's connected with android studio, I can unplug the phone and it still works**. In Huawei there is an option in developer options "Allow ADB debugging in load only mode", we can disable it and it works without charging the phone. On s10e there is no such option, I think that it is allowed by default and we can't change it.

Comment: True. Only connecting the phone to a charger fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks tried everything. However, connecting to the charger solved the issue.

Comment: The same "Allow ADB Debugging" is also present in OnePlus. I disabled it And it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I periodically get this problem (Pairing Android Studio on my Mac to Android Phone, the Computer just hangs after phone scans QR code).  When I disable and then re-enable wifi debugging on the Android phone, it connects on the next attempt.

Comment: Thx Peter; i've been scratching head and tried loads of suggestions; this one worked.

Answer (score 1):

1. Turn off and turn on Wi-Fi on your phone.
2. [Ping](https://linuxize.com/post/linux-ping-command/) the phone firstly: `ping 192.168.1.97`. You should see that packets are transmitted.
3. Now you highly likely can connect to the phone using QR-code or `adb pair`

Comment: What exactly does "Ping the phone firstly: ping 192.168.1.97" mean? Can you (or anyone) please tell me the steps?

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård You should run a `ping` command with the ip of your device. The purpose of this action is to check that your device is available within your wi-fi network. For unknown reasons, a phone can "disappear" from the network. When your turn off and turn on wi-fi, you force you phone to became visible withing the network. Using `ping` command you just check that your device is visible for another computers withing the wi-fi network.

Comment: And how do I run this `ping` command, please?

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård this is a command that you type in a linux/windows/mac terminal. Try to google about it...

Comment: I HAVE googled about it, and that's how I ended up on this page... ‍♀️ And I'm sure many other people will also google and end up here, because if you haven't noticed, StackOverflow pages tend to come up first in google searches! And for a good reason, because other SO users usually tell you exactly how to solve your problem. Step by step, and with exact terminal commands written down. That's what this forum is for. Too bad you are not equally helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to pair (Windows 11), by doing this:

1. Disable wireless debugging on the Android device
2. Toggle the computer's WiFi off/on
3. Re-enable wireless debugging
4. Click "Pair using Wi-Fi" in Android studio

Answer (score 1):

I have reinstalled platform-tools and it helped.

Answer (score 1):

open terminal and type
`cd %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\sdk\platform-tools`
`./adb connect <device_ip>:<device_port>`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.
QR Code, Pairing code, or even connecting manually with the "adb connect [phone_ip]:[port]" method didn't work.
However, the problem was solved as soon as I **disabled** the "**AP isolation**" option on the **modem settings**.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update SDK Platform-Tool and Build-tools.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with the file "devices.xml" located in $USER_FOLDER/.android
I have renamed it and the problem goes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33650187)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I tried was restarting wifi & it worked. I didn't try other solutions though! So for those, who didn't get the answer, you can try restarting wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Updating SDK Build Tools and SDK Platform Tools did the trick for me and now the connection works.

To update those, go to Tools > SDK Manager > Select SDK Tools > Check Android SDK Build-Tools and Android SDK Platform-Tools and press Install.

After installing the latest updates, I restarted Android Studio and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The command is

```
adb pair <ip>:<port>
```

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally came up with the simplest solution to the problem, which requires only one universal command and works mostly stable. It works if you have already connected your device and your computer is listed under "Connected Devices" in your phone's Wireless Debugging settings.

Once you have enabled Wireless Debugging on your Android 11+, all you have to do is write `adb devices` in the terminal. If you notice a delay, that's fine - your device will connect in a few seconds. If there's no delay, you should probably turn off and on Wireless Debugging on your device and try `adb devices` again.

Previously, `adb kill-server` has helped me, and you should definitely try it if `adb devices` didn't work.

To avoid typing `adb devices` every time, I recommend [adding a custom button in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62128025/how-to-add-custom-action-to-intellij-idea/77736735#77736735).

Answer (score 0):

I have to reboot my ubuntu desktop before wifi pairing works. Still frequently better than using a cable. :-)