# Wi-Fi Debug (ADB) - There was an error pairing the device

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-bumblebee

When I first update to new version of studio I tried to use this new WiFi debug feature and it was working at first time (using QR code or manually typing the code) but now it's stuck with `"Connecting to device. This takes up to 2 minutes."` message for some time and then I get `"There was an error pairing the device"` message. Before it would take a couple of seconds to connect. My device is Samsung S10 (12 Android)

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue this morning... did you find a solution?

Comment: i have the same device and the same problem. Hope there is a solution.

Comment: Same problem on samsung device, but after I switch off and on wireless debugging  again it connected.

Comment: @DonMadrino https://stackoverflow.com/a/72797607/7767664

Comment: @Nikola https://stackoverflow.com/a/72797607/7767664

Comment: Simplest solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77745022/12544067

Answer (score 47):

I was able to resolve the issue from within Wi-Fi settings by disabling the Randomized MAC Address feature under Privacy. Using my device's actual MAC address fixes the issue.

[image: Android Wi-Fi Settings]

Comment: This worked for me. Randomized MAC was problem.

Comment: this is the solution.

Comment: This didn't work for me

Comment: yeah, I guess it makes a lot of sense, will test it and accept your answer later if everything is good

Answer (score 39):

---

EDIT 2: Take a look at the below answers, the actual reason seems to be that the device is assigned a random IP or a MAC via DHCP, if you can disable that via system settings for your specific custom ROM, then it's even better

---

---

EDIT: If you see regular disconnections, click on `Pair Device with Pairing Code`, and then pair your device with the following command

```
adb pair <ip-addr>:<port> <pairing_code>
```

---

I was facing the same issue, what I did was switching to the command line way of connecting with the device. You can do so in the following way

1. Make sure `USB Debugging` is enabled on the device you intend to connect with
2. In your device, go to `Developer Settings>Wireless Debugging` and you will see something like so

[image: Sample Screenshot]

3. Now carefully look at the `IP ADDRESS AND PORT` section and type the following in the terminal

```bash
  adb connect <ip-addr>:<port>
```

And your computer will show under paired devices like the above screenshot

Comment: The second way does not work. I get "no route to host" and tcpip throws an error saying their are no devices.

Comment: First way failed saying Unable to start pairing client

Comment: "Make sure USB Debugging is enabled on the device you intend to connect with" is important ... even though you are using Wireless debugging, if USB debugging is not on, it just doesn't work.

Comment: Restarting the Android device fixed "Unable to start pairing" this issue for me

Comment: Even worse, I get the following message in the terminal, "adb : The term 'adb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."

Comment: basically it's not a solution but just another method to connect when first one fails, eventually it may temporary fix the normal way but after some time it will fail again and need to do all that stuff again

Answer (score 8):

**I had the same problem but I managed to find the solution.
You have to follow the following steps:**

1. In your smartphone (**Go to Settings->Developer options-> Wireless Debugging->Pair device with pairing code**).
2. Copy the ipaddress & port.
   For example: **192.168.1.2:42123**
   and wifi pairing code: **234321**.
3. Open your terminal and go to the following path:
   **cd  %LOCALAPPDATA%/Android/sdk/platform-tools**
4. Paste the following command following this order:
   ***adb pair (ipaddress & port that you saw when you clicked on "Pair device with pairing code")***
   **adb pair 192.168.1.2:42123**
5. Paste the access code to the wifi connection.
   **Enter pairing code: 41107.**
6. Finally, on the same screen go to the option that says IP address and port and you
   will see the same address but with another port ([You can find it in this part of your screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVtgf.png)), copy it and write the following
   command:
   **adb connect 192.168.1.2:41107**

If you see a message like this ***"connected to 192.168.1.2:41107"***, you did it you will be able to connect your phone with android studio without any problem.

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and mine?

Answer (score 5):

This really helped me

### **Using Terminal Tool**

**Pairing**: `

1. enable **wireless debugging**
2. click on **Pair device with pairing code**
3. in **terminal** type: `adb pair {ip_address}:{port} {pairing_code}`
4. you will see your pc **name** below **Paired devices**
   `

**Connecting**: `

1. Note **ip** and **port** found above **Pair device with QR code** [VERY IMPORTANT]
2. in **terminal** type: `adb connect {ip_address}:{port}`
3. you will see **Currently connected** below your **pc name** ,congrats :)

**Note**:
next time you can use **Connecting** step if your pc already **paired**

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by manually assigning IP addresses for my smartphone and PC at settings of the router. Basically avoiding DHCP.

Restarted the router.

Cleared old pairing.

Started pairing again and now it works fine all the time, and no need to repeat pairing process, just enabling "Wireless debugging" from notification panel and in couple of seconds the device will be available in Android Studio

So next time just enable "Wireless debugging" and it's ready

[image]

I don't know why there the issue with dynamic IPs

p.s.: though I'm not sure if using the same IP address really fixes it (need to test it for sure), so can't accept any answer for now

Answer (score 3):

Note that for me pairing wouldn't work while I was on my VPN. After I paired while off the VPN, I could `adb connect ipaddress:port` and it worked.

Comment: nobody mentioned VPN, well thanks for this one, it solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

- **Tools** --> Troubleshoot Device Connections
- Press Next --> Next
- Click '**Restart ADB server**'
- Freshly turn ON **Wireless Debugging** on device and wait for few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to give you a age old solution

1. Turn off Developer Options
2. Turn On Developer Options
3. Turn on USB Debugging
4. Turn On Wireless Debugging
5. Try to connect with QR Code
6. Be Happy when you see that turning this off and on still is a solution to many complex problems

Answer (score 0):

enable the USB debugging option in your mobile device and then retry connecting through wireless option, It will work

In my case It worked

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I initially got this error as well, but was able to successfully pair successfully after restarting the device.

Answer (score -2):

Important reminder and this is what solved my problem.

**Devices must be on the same network.**