# Wireless Android Debugging Not Showing Available Devices or Connecting

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-wireless

I am using Android Studio Chipmunk edition.

My android device is connected to the Wifi and my PC is connected to the same router through Ethernet cable.

My devices are running Android 12.

So, it seems like I am fulfilling all the requirements.

I was able to connect a few times and able to install apps wirelessly. However, I am failing now. One of the following two things happens each time:

The QR scanner does not do anything when I scan the code as if it didn't recognize the QR code at all.

The QR code is recognized and I get a message about the pairing taking a while.

I also tried using the six digit code for pairing by none of my devices are showing up under "Available Wi-fi Devices". What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio BumbleBee pair wifi not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70905560/android-studio-bumblebee-pair-wifi-not-working)

Comment: Thanks @plplmax The accepted solution there did not work for me. I did get the message about successful pairing but the device is still not listed to be online under available devices.